# Instance that returns value (not instance) when called directly

Tags: python, class, inheritance, object, overloading

I would like a class whose instances return a value when called directly as if they inherit from int, float, str, etc.  I imagine it's overloading some function **???**:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def somefunction(self):
        if isintance(self.value, int):
            return 5
        else:
            return 'something else'

    def __???__(self):
        return self.value

a = A(2)
a + 5 # 7
a.somefunction() # 5

a = A('foo')
a + "bar" # 'foobar'
a.somefunction() # 'something else'
```

I can't simply subclass int as the value could be of different types.

Is this doable?  Perhaps there's a good reason that this can't be done, but it's late, and I can't think of it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding `__getattr__` won't work because of metaclass confusion; the issue is that the relevant methods need to be in the instance's class dict.

If you're happy with `value` being immutable, one way could be to override `__new__` and construct classes on demand:

```
def __new__(cls, value):
    return type("A", (type(value), A), {})(value)
```

Note that this puts `A` after `type(value)` in the mro; this is necessary to stop `__new__` resulting in runaway recursion!  If there's methods on `A` that should override those on `type(value)`, you can put them into the dict 3rd argument to `type()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `a.value + 'bar'`, or you can define `__add__` method

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, arg):
        return self.value + arg


a = A(2)
print a + 5           # 7

a = A('foo')
print a.value + "bar" # 'foobar'
print a + "bar"       # 'foobar'
```

Python functions and methods are a kind of generic (you can think of the similarity with C++ templates).  The `+` operator, for example, works both for numeric types and for strings.  You cannot mix the types; however, the type checking of the operands is done dynamically, when the operation is going to be executed.  This way, the `__add__` method works both for integers and strings (and complex, and floats,...).

If you want to display the value of the instance when printing (i.e. not performing the `+` operation), you can define the `__str__` method:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```

Comment: `print a` won't print `2` or `foo`, however. I'm not sure if the OP is OK with that.

Comment: @Lev Levitsky: This is a different request.  The `print` converts the object into a readable string.  You can use the `__repr__` method to convert the object to a *technical* string representation, or the `__str__` method to convert it to the *human readable* string representation.  The `__str__` method is called by the `print` automatically, or you can use the built-in `str()` function to call the `__str__`.

Comment: The way I understand the question is that `a` should _evaluate to_ `2` (or `'foo'`) in any context, be it addition or something else.

Comment: @Lev Levitsky:  In the case, I would personally use the simple `a.value`.  Or there are all the other `__operator__` methods to be implemented.  There is no magic to do it automatically.  The object is not a single value from inside.  The value from the object must be extracted somehow.

Comment: The `a` can never be generally treated as any value stored inside.  The reason is that `a` is simply a reference to an object.  For example, when doing `b = a`, the reference is assigned to the same object, not to another object with the value.  In other words, you can never get `b = a.value` by just typing `b = a`.  If you want to do anything close to that general requirement, the object must always be considered in some context.  Because of that you need to define the operators like `__add__`, `__str__`, or whatever to make the `a` behave the wanted way in the context.

Comment: I gave a bad example; Lev is correct that a should evaluate to 2 in any context be it addition or something else.